# Integrating TabBarIOS with StatusBar

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

Has anyone managed to integrate the `TabBarIOS` component with the `StatusBar` component? I'm trying to do so but don't seem to be getting anywhere. Things I've tried -

- Adding `StatusBar` as a child of `TabBarIOS` - Throws an error because `TabBarIOS` only takes `TabBarIOS.Item` components as children.
- Putting `StatusBar` and `TabBarIOS` on the same level and then wrapping the entire thing in a `View` - Entire `TabBarIOS` component falls apart and renders almost entirely out of the screen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So TabBarIOS should have multiple child items. What I did is to nest the StatusBar under each Child of TabBarIOS.

For Example, on the login page, I have something like this...

```
<View style={styles.xxx}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"/>
      <Text>StyleBar is now in white</Text>
</View>
```

and when it got prompted to the other page with TabBarIOS.

```
    <TabBarIOS.Item
      selected = {this.state.selectedTab ==='xxx'}
      title='xxx'
      onPress={() => {
          this.setState({
              selectedTab: 'xxx',
          });
      }}>
        <View>
           <StatusBar barStyle="default"/>
        <Text> Style is set back to Default, you can do whatever you like!</Text>
       </View>
    </TabBarIOS.Item>
```

Hope this helps.